# How to show http server error message in message box using c#?

Tags: c#, http

how to get the proper error message from http server and display it in message box using c#.for example:for 204 status code server response "content not found".

how can i check response status,error message and displaying error message in message box using c#.

please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: read this article and create some code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10593/Error-Handling-in-ASP-NET